# protect hash code?

Tags: security, hash, shared-hosting, vps, salt

I'm sure there's something fundamental to all of this that simplifies the whole concept that I'm missing, but here goes:

OK, you salt & hash passwords for security, but what about the code that does it?

If you're on a host or vps, can't "someone" get ahold of your source b/c you compiled it there?  Or, if they can access your database, can't they access the program that does the encryption/decryption and bruteforce it until they get the algorithm?

I know nothing can ever be 100% secure, but how can security be improved in this context?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs's_principle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salting will protect the data somewhat from a dictionary or rainbow table attack in the case that your data was compromised.  Brute force is not impossible, but will be slow and will need to be performed again for each password hash.  If salting was not done, brute force attacks become much easier to attain.

Contrary to what some say, the salt is not protected in any special way (nor does it need to be), but is present in plain text as appended to the hash.  It *does* however, need to be unique for each hash or it becomes pointless for this use.  This is in contrast to a pepper that is used for all hashes and *must* be protected.  Because of this distinction, salting is generally preferred unless access to the pepper is guaranteed to be restricted (not an easy task).

If you want improved security, don't use a shared host.  And don't allow direct access to the database.  And don't allow anyone that hasn't been prescreened to access your system.  In a practical sense, these aren't always viable options.  So just use a salt and live with it :)

Comment: lol, last paragraph says it all

Comment: @PinnyM: Help me understand the claim that a salt need not be protected.  If I *know* the salt used in conjunction with a particular account, can I not construct a rainbow table just as effortlessly as if the password were unsalted?

Comment: @EricJ. - Yes you could use this salt to build a rainbow-table, but when you apply a different salt for each password, then you would have to build such a table for each password. Nobody will do this, because brute-force is faster, if you have found a match it doesn't make sense to build the rest of the rainbow-table. To the salt and pepper: they do not exclude each other, a salt is a must, a pepper helps in some cases to protect weak passwords.

Comment: @martinstoeckli: If the salt is known, brute forcing becomes much more trivial as well, as I need only take the password guess plus salt and create a hash, rather than permuting all possible password plus salt values.  Weak passwords therefore remain weak.

Comment: @EricJ. salting isn't designed to protect weak passwords per se.  It's designed to not allow a single rainbow table to crack them all in one pass.  Since a separate table would need to be created for each one, this significantly increases the amount of time to brute force all passwords by several orders of magnitude.  You are correct, however, that a single password can be brute-forced within the same timeframe. Trying to keep the salt hidden will likely not provide much benefit, since in the event that the database was compromised what are the odds that the code base (and salt) wasn't?

Comment: @EricJ - also, a brute-force attack has a greater advantage when large numbers of passwords are available for sampling.  However, when a salt has been added this advantage is eliminated since each salt needs to be tested separately.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) for more info on this.

Comment: @EricJ. - The purpose of the salt is, that you must brute-force each password separately. The purpose of the pepper is, that (as long as it remains secret) weak passwords become strong combinations of password and pepper. To thwart brute-forcing a single password, you need a slow hash function like BCrypt. Have a look at my [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing "hidden" in your source code regarding the hash algorithm.  In fact, you should be using a proven, well-known implementation of a strong hash and not implementing the algorithm yourself.

The salt is the part that needs to be protected.  That salt is not part of your code (or should not be) but rather should be stored in some sort of file storage / data base (depending on your application), and should be applied on a per-user bases (user Joe should have a different salt for his password than user Fred).

To be sure, it is critically important to protect the salt used with each user's password.  That's where proper file system / database permissions come into play.

On another note, your *code* should also be protected from any unauthorized user as well, but not for the reason of protecting the salt (at least not directly... if someone can access the salt, or just *replace* your code with their own, entirely bypassing the authentication check).

Comment: The salt is generally not considered as a secret.